# Display Categories Assigned to a Post

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, tags

I'm trying to add a custom breadcrumb that displays all the categories each project belongs to. The categories aren't displaying. http://test.naeng.com/main/project/st-michael-secondary-catholic-school/

```
      <!--      breadcrumbs-->
      <div class="clearBoth"></div>
      <div id="dcp-sectionlinks">
          <a href="/main/featured-project/">See Featured Projects</a>
          <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category'); ?>
          <?php if (count($terms)>0): ?>
              | Discipline(s): 
              <?php foreach($terms as $oneDiscipline):?>
                  <a href="/main/projects-<?php echo($oneDiscipline->slug);?>"><?php echo($oneDiscipline->name); ?></a>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      <div id="bottomhome"><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>">Home</a></div>
      <!--      breadcrumbs end-->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are querying the default `category` base for WP you can consider using the [get_the_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) function.

Also I saw you source code of the page and noticed that your `if` loop isn't running, `var_dump` the `$terms` variable and check if its returning items or not and check if the post id is working correctly. You can consider replacing `$post->ID` with [get_the_ID()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) function just to be sure ..